How to copy a table in Big Query, with primary keys
I have a table in Big Query, which is partitioned, has primary keys and some clustering keys as well. I want to rename this table. Big Query docs mention that tables can be renamed using:
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable RENAME TO mynewtable;

I tried it, and it worked when the table was partitioned. However, if the table contained any Primary Keys then BQ said it was not allowed. This limitation is not mentioned in the docs. Given this, what are the options to rename/copy a partitioned table which has PKs and clustering keys. I know that I can first re-create the target table with the appropriate partitioning, PKs and clustering and then use
INSERT INTO <Target_Table> SELECT * FROM <Source_Table>

Is there any alternative where I do not have to re-create the target table first?

Because it's not documented, you can fill a bug. It might be a bug !

Instead of tinkering with table, just drop primary key(s), rename table and recreate primary keys:
Both foreign keys and primary keys in BQ are not enforced - it should be way faster than recreating table all together.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_drop_primary_key_statement
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_primary_key_statement

As there is no specific document on ALTER TABLE RENAME TO with primary key and there is limitation to use ‘ALTER TABLE RENAME TO’ rename a partition table with the primary key. What you can do is to re-create the table like you do, then using INSERT INTO to add data into the table.
On Google side, there is a ‘Feature Request’ that you can file but there is no timeline on when it can be done. This feature might be developed in the future to get the output as you desired.

Another option, besides re-creating the table and then doing "INSERT INTO <Target_Table> SELECT * FROM <Source_Table>" is to use "bq cp mydataset.mytable mydataset2.mytable2". It's there in the google docs, not sure how I missed it. Seems it should be simpler/quicker than the "INSERT INTO ..." option though I have not compared.
EDIT:
I have found that using table clones seems to be a workaround to renaming tables in a way. Clone source tables to target and then delete the source tables. Performance is similar to renaming since both are metadata operations. There is one extra step of deleting the source tables but you are not restricted by the PK constraints and can also clone across projects unlike while renaming tables. Since clones are not full copies you also don't pay for extra storage during the process. Not sure if there are any potential issues with this approach since this is not the use case for table clones.
